# Protecting FET with Zener

Tags: mosfet, zener

[image]

In shown schematic, I would like to know by any chance or cause if Zener D9 will get damaged. If yes what are all possibilities?

FSK signal consist of 3Hz and 6Hz signal all together.

Comment: @KingDuken,    link **Out** will go out of the board to different board which is consist of FSK discriminator ( converting to digital ) and share the same GND. As I mentioned in schematic it will have load 500mA max wrt GND.

Comment: It helps if you explain the background to your question. I'm guessing you've got boards where D9 keeps failing? The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: I am doing FMEA, just making sure everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output is suddenly shorted the zener current is not limited. It will carry the charge current of the 4.4uF level-shifting capacitance.

Something similar might happen if the higher supply voltage is suddenly applied and the load is low-Z.

Comment: Exactly same thing I was thinking, that't why I marked  both caps.

Comment: I am thinking to use TVS in place of zener here.